# Update image in Tkinter menu item on hover or when Active

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I can't seem to find any information about updating an image in a Tkinter menu item on hover or when it's active or gets focus. Does anyone know if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your label that holds the image:

```
imageLabel = Label(root,image=image1)
imageLabel.pack()
```

Then you need to bind the function for the mouse going over it out leaving it to change the image:

```
def image_two(event):
    imageLabel["image"] = image2
def image_one(event):
    imageLabel["image"] = image1
imageLabel.bind("<Enter>", image_two)
imageLabel.bind("<Leave>", image_one)
```

I tested this on windows 10 python 3.6.5 and it works, please comment if you have any further questions.

Comment: I don't think that works in this case because the mouse may be over the text on the menu item not the image when entering or leaving. What you have suggested only works when mouse enters or leaves the image, I need capture mouse enter and exit on the complete menu item line so that includes the text as well as the image. I don't know if this is possible tho.

Comment: if there is an image in the label, there is no text

Comment: Yes you can have both an image and "text beside it" in a menu item.

Comment: Then don't do it like that!